# Numbers in function parameters in documentation?

Tags: c, linux, code-documentation

I've been trying to read up on some C libraries from [die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep), and I'm a bit thrown off by numbers inside parameters, i.e:

> See Also
> alarm(2), nanosleep(2), signal(2), signal(7)
>
> Referenced By
> aio(7), clock_nanosleep(2), getitimer(2), perlfaq5(1), pth(3), sleep(1), time(7), ualarm(3), upslog(8), usleep(3)

The only time I've known to put anything in actual parameters in documentation is when I give example code. But this clearly isn't example code. In fact, several of these functions don't even take integers for parameters.

I don't understand why they would say `signal(2)` when they could just say `signal()`.

What do the numbers mean?

Comment: The number is the [section of the manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) referencing that function. Different functions/utilitis can appear by name in more than one place in the overall manual schema.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

Comment: Read [the`man` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/man).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com, but already has a duplicate there.

Comment: @Tanktalus I think it's better to close as a duplicate rather than off-topic.

Comment: I suggest [POSIX.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for documentation rather than die.net (unless you really need linuxy stuff, in which case I have no suggestions).

Comment: @FunnyGeeks I tried, but because it's on a different site of the stack exchange network, and not stack overflow, I couldn't. (Otherwise, I agree with you.)

Comment: This has been asked more than once before.  There should be a good Q&A somewhere on SO (as well as on other SE sites).